# Scientist invents time travel. Proposes selling use of it to students who want extra weeks to revise. Possibly Heinlein

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

I read this in the 80s or 90s. Cannot remember if it was part of a novel or a short story. I have a feeling it might be Heinlein. The time travel may have been part of, or a side effect of inventing cross dimensional travel.

I remember thinking just how useful such a thing might be when revising for exams.

I know this one is a long shot. Sorry I can't remember more details.

Comment: How would time travel help students study? Was it time travel or a "time freeze"?

Comment: It might have been either. Time travel to 3 weeks in the past would give students 3 extra weeks to revise.

Comment: But I think it may indeed have been time freeze from my memory.

Comment: The protagonist in the great classic Heinlein story "By His Bootstraps"  is a college student who is behind on his work. The story is all about time travel. But much of it does not match the question.

Answer (score 8):

This could be "[Time for Sale](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?67962)" (1938) by Ralph Milne Farley, originally published in the [August 1938 issue of Amazing Stories](https://archive.org/details/Amazing_Stories_v12n04_1938-08). The beginning of the story features a young man asking his father for money:

"But Dad," his son remonstrated "wouldn't it be worth two thousand dollars to you for me to graduate from college? All that stands in the way of my Engineering degree is tomorrow's exam in Physics, and I have a deal which should get me through it. Ony $500 down, and $1,500 more if I pass."

The son intends to use the services of P. Langford Hatch of Entrophy, Inc., who has invented a device that creates a zone of different time within it by altering the rate of entropy. As explained by the inventor:

"Step in, gentlemen," he invited. "I shall have to *lock* you in, for it would be disastrous for you to emerge while the coils are energized. Stay in there two weeks and tutor Mr. Porter for his exam. You will note that the glass will become black and impervious to sight and light, as soon as the current is turned on. When the glass clears, you can come out. It will then be only seven o'clock tomorrow morning."

After passing his exam, the young man returns to Entrophy, Inc., where he is tricked into the device and left there with it running by the inventor. He emerges many years later after a power failure halts the machine.

Comment: Not the one I remember but I great story I intend to read too. 